# PHP Interfaces and namespaces

Tags: php, laravel, design-patterns, interface, fig

When developing a package or application is there a best practice, FIG standard or community consensus on where to place class interfaces in consideration to namespacing?

For example should we:

- `App\CarInterface`
- `App\Cars\Ford`
- `App\Cars\Toyota`
- `App\Cars\Tesla`

Or should we:

- `App\Cars\CarInterface`
- `App\Cars\Ford`
- `App\Cars\Toyota`
- `App\Cars\Tesla`

I'm asking should interfaces be placed in the same namespaces as their implementations.

Comment: The class names should emerge from the concept used in the project. The same for interfaces and namespaces. Are all the classes of your application located in the `App` namespace?

Comment: What I like to do in this case is the second option, but instead of `CarInterface` I'd just name it `Car`. Then you use the interface for declaring dependencies, and pass implementations as needed

Comment: @axiac I don't understand what you mean? I'm asking should interfaces be placed in the same namespaces as their implementations....

Comment: I couldn't edit my previous answer properly within the stupid 5 minute time limit. I wasn't aware that those are actually [PSR naming conventions](https://www.php-fig.org/bylaws/psr-naming-conventions/) as noted in the other answer below, so ignore my note on Symfony. Suffixing interface names with *Interface appears to be a PHP-FIG standard that Symfony follows. Doesn't mean you _must_ follow, but it helps to keep things consistent.

Answer (score 0):

In illuminate's case all interfaces are in `illuminate/contracts/<<FunctionGroup>>/<<BarInterface>>`

But, if you think that'll be harder for you to maintain/find the relevant interface, go with your second option. I see many projects that are organize that way (including mine).

By the way, from [PSR Naming Conventions](https://www.php-fig.org/bylaws/psr-naming-conventions/)

> Interfaces MUST be suffixed by `Interface`: e.g. `Psr\Foo\BarInterface`.

Comment: I really dislike the Illuminate method, it kind of works for a framework. It separates contracts from their implementations so greatly you have to delve into a completely different package / submodule to find them

Comment: Yeah, that's why I prefer to group it near where it should be implement. And only use `contracts` for global/widely used interface.